# How do I write a list of strings to a CSV file, with each item of the list on a new row?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of strings as follows:

```
sentence = ['this stuff', 'is not','that easy']
```

And I want to write to a csv file, with each item in the list on a different line.

When I use the code below,

```
with open(os.path.join(path, 'testlist.csv'), 'w') as my_file:
    f_writer = csv.writer(my_file)
    f_writer.writerow(sentence)
```

I get the following as output:

```
this stuff,is not,that easy
```

How do I get each item of the list on a different row?

Comment: This smells like a homework question.  There are several ways to do that very simply, and some don't even use the csv module. (A one-line print statement will do.)  But I'll give you clue a clue for a csv way:  look in the csv module documentation for "delimiter"

Comment: Do you want to keep the commas?

Comment: Ha, it smells like one but isn't! I  have basically scraped a blogpost, and want to print each p tag into a separate row in a csv file. I have simplified it to post here. I don't need the commas. Thanks for the tip - will check out delimiters as well

Comment: I gave a more explicit, slightly tongue-in-cheek answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since others have given you some answers, here you go in Python 3.x:

```
print (*sentence,sep='\n',file=open(os.path.join(path, 'testlist.csv'), 'w'))
```

or in Python 2.7 you could do:

```
print open(os.path.join(path, 'testlist.csv'), 'w'),"\n".join(sentence)
```

(neither of the above need the csv module)

In your example, I think you can just change

```
f_writer = csv.writer(my_file)
```

to

```
f_writer = csv.writer(my_file, delimiter='\n')
```

And in a real stretch, you could probably instead change:

```
 f_writer.writerow(sentence)
```

to

```
 f_writer.writerows(list([x] for x in sentence))
```

Happy Pythoning!

Comment: I ran this code with the delimiter:
```sentence = ['this stuff', 'is not','that easy']
with open('test.csv', 'w') as my_file:
    f_writer = csv.writer(my_file, delimiter='\n')
    for s in sentence: f_writer.writerow([s])```
the csv file looks like this (since I can't show new lines on comments, I'm using \n):
```t\n
h\n
i\n
s\n
 \n
s\n
t\n
u\n
f\n
f\n```

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum it works with the delimiter but you don't need the loop - it worked using  writerow

Comment: Thanks Rufus, I have plenty of options to work through and understand. Your last suggestion essentially converts each item in sentence into a list and then writes that list as a separate row? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: As @Chadmeistr said: Don't use the for loop.

Comment: You got it, @Chadmeistr.  But I have to tell you , I just did it from keyboard, untested.

Comment: @RufusVS Awesome. I shall get there, one day ;)

Answer (score 1):

write row take a list and writes it in one row separated by `,` if you want the elements of the row on separate lines

pass them one by one

```
sentence = ['this stuff', 'is not','that easy']
with open(os.path.join(path, 'testlist.csv'), 'w') as my_file:
    f_writer = csv.writer(my_file)
    for s in sentence: f_writer.writerow([s])
    # f_writer.writerow(sentence)
```

Comment: Interesting that using f_writer.writerow(s) prints it out with commas, while f_writer.writerow([s]) prints out without commas. What's going on there?!

Comment: if you give it a list, it knows that the row has 1 element while otherwise, it takes the string chars as elements

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, using [s] basically treats each item in the original  list as a single item list. Which is then printed on a separate row?

Comment: bingo, yes. you can also use `writerows` which takes list of list as an input, where each list is a row

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```py
import pandas as pd
sentence = ['this stuff', 'is not','that easy']
sent = pd.Series(sentence)
sent.to_csv('file.csv', header = False)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do it without pandas?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the `csv` module. There are tons of utilities that can help you with this task. I think pandas approach is the easiest and faster one.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use lists within the "sentence"

2) Replace "writerow" with "writerows"

Eg:

```
# Change 1
sentence = [['this stuff'], ['is not'],['that easy']]

with open(os.path.join(path, 'testlist.csv'), 'w') as my_file:
    f_writer = csv.writer(my_file)
# Change 2
    f_writer.writerows(sentence)
```